# Sculpting on 2 joined meshes is not working as intended

Tags: modeling, sculpting

The problem I'm having is that when I join 2 object and make them into one and continue sculpting as a result I start getting these blobs and won't connect with previous second mesh
[image]
These were the 2 meshes that I joined (the upper rectangle one and the lower cylindric one). I intended for them to be smooth surfaces but their "geometry" is never connecting.

Comment: joining two objects won't merge their mesh, to do so you need to boolean

Comment: How can I do that? If I use boolean Union I got few copies of the original mesh for some reason it mirror modifier didn't work correctly after that.

Comment: you can go in Edit mode, select one of your meshes with L, then go in the header menu > Face > Intersect (Boolean), then tweak the settings in the Operator box

Comment: After following the steps you suggested mesh which I selected with L disappeared. In the Operator box I can bring it back but when I select select anything else nothing seems to happen.

Comment: or try with a Boolean modifier instead of merging the 2 objects?

Comment: I used boolean modifier and now I've got a duplicate object of the select one and sculpting in-build mirror option is not mirroring correctly

Comment: it's hard to help, maybe share your file or at least a part of it, use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ or https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/M0SVn3Zk Like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you want to sculpt these two objects together:

[image]

First, apply their scale, then apply all their modifiers except *Subdivision Surface* that you just disable. Keep in mind that when you join objects, the last selected while keep its modifiers (and they will affect the joined meshes) while the others won't:

[image]

Join them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>, then select all the meshes except one and go into *Face > Intersect (Boolean)* and in the *Operator* box choose *Boolean > Union*:

[image]

Set the origin of the object to its geometry, switch to *Sculpt* mode, enable *Dyntopo*, it works:

[image]

Comment: So that's how it's done! Thank you.

Comment: Hey Moonboots, I have the same problem again but now I have a mirrored object that's not connected to anything and when I try connecting them with the method you suggested that had worked until now, the other (mirrored) object disappears. It's hard for me to explain. Can you take a look at it? Send a comment here and I'll send you a blend file. Thank you.

Comment: yes ok please share the file

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/GmQRsegE 
I have a problem with the "Cube.012" where I can't get boolean to work correctly.

Comment: if you're talking about merging Cube012 with Cone011, switch the Boolean modifier from Solver > Exact to Fast, sometimes the Boolean doesn't work for some reason and you need to switch to the other method (Exact should work better though as it accepts overlapping vertices/faces/edges, but it's not the case here, I don't know why)

Comment: Yes, switching boolean to fast method worked perfectly. Weird indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a boolean workflow, consider joining and then remeshing specifically. Keep in mind that the voxel-sizes will need to be selected appropriately for the right level of tessellation to represent the surfaces you are working with.

It also helps if both surfaces used have roughly the same level of fidelity, though this isn't always essential provided the surfaces have a reasonable level of tesselation.

Joining and remeshing a low polygon object to a high polygon object makes inferring the volume of the objects not always work properly if the poly-counts differ a lot -- so sometimes you might want to subdivide the object with the lower polycount (especially if it was created using hard modelling or box modelling techniques -- and another was made of organic or sculpting techniques).